# Simple interference confocal microscope

Tags: optics, polarization, microscopy, image-processing

I have the two articles:

The first one: [First article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236011595_A_Confocal_Interference_Microscope)

and

The second one: [Second article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.2c07007)

After reading the first article I understood while reading that using the detector A we get confocal interference image (with strips).

Reading the second article, I noticed that construction is similar and they don't use second detector as in first article (detector B) and they get an image with no strips.

So, how the second method works?

I understand that in the first article, the second detector (detector B) measures the intensity of wave moved by half wavelength. Is it possible to not use the second detector (detector B) but use a system of polarizators to create image without strips only by measuring with detector A?